# Add multiple number of months to specific date until date in future - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In Google Sheets I need calculate next date in future from TODAY based on start date adding specific number of months (or multiple of them). When I will open it everytime in future it will always calculate correct date.

Example:

Today is 2021-12-01

- Start date = 2021-02-07, interval = 5 months => next date should be 2021-12-07
- Start date = 2021-09-07, interval = 3 months => next date should be 2021-12-07
- Start date = 2021-09-07, interval = 12 months => next date should be 2022-12-07
- Start date = 2021-12-07, interval = 12 months => next date should be 2021-12-07

Idealy would be to have 3 cells: start date, interval, future date.
I have no idea how to do it using one "unversal" formula.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
=DATE(YEAR(A1),(MONTH(A1)+B1),DAY(A1))
```

Where:

A1 = Start date

B1 = Interval

C1 = Formula (Next date)

Comment: ohh.. sorry... I wrote it not precisely enough.
 I need calculate next date in future from TODAY based on start date